# JScrollPane: How to resize automatically the JPanel contained in the scroll

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm working on a little applet that has a list of items in a JScrollPane on the left.

the user will be able to add and remove elements from this list.

therefore I need to create a scrollable list.

this part is easy.

I'm usually tempted to do most of the GUI resizing by hand but I read in the doc of the JScrollPane that it is better to let swing handle it rather than manually changing the dimension.

the problem is that I keep adding element and the inside panel doesn't change size.

any ideas?

here is some of the code I'm using:
constructor:

```
public SideBarView(Dimension d) {

        super(d);
        Dimension d2 = new Dimension(100,300);

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        //INSIDE VIEW (zone that is being scrolled)
        container = new SideBarContainer(d2);

//      container.setSize(d2);
//      container.setPreferredSize(d2);
//      container.setMaximumSize(d2);
//      container.setMinimumSize(d2);


        scrollPane = new MyJScrollPane(container);

        new ImageLoaderWorker(this,menuButton).execute();

        Dimension d3 = new Dimension(d.width, d.height-d.width);
        scrollPane.setSize(d3);
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(d3);
        scrollPane.setMinimumSize(d3);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(d3);

        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
}
```

Adding to container:

```
element = new JPanel();
        Dimension d2 = new Dimension(100,100);

        element.setSize(d2);
        element.setPreferredSize(d2);
        element.setMaximumSize(d2);
        element.setMinimumSize(d2);

        element.setBackground((panelcount++%2==0)?Color.BLUE:Color.RED);
        cointainer.add(element);
```

any idea what I'm missing ? or should I just resize the container by hand as I go along?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the container to lay out the components. This is done by revalidating the panel:

```
container.add(element); 
container.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
panel.setSize(d2);
panel.setPreferredSize(d2);
panel.setMaximumSize(d2);
panel.setMinimumSize(d2);
```

This let's no option to resize for swing, since you tell the layout manager to use exactly the size of d2 (100/100).

Try without `setMaximumSize` and `setPreferredSize`. You might need to invalidate the panel or scrollpane after adding/removing content as well.

Edit: 
I think I considered `panel`to be your containter. Could you provide the setup code for your scrollpane and the container?

Did you set a layout manager for the container?

Comment: Actually the code your refering to (the adding to container), is list of elements I want to scroll over, so their size is fixed, in the constructor you'll notice that all the "container" settings are the defaults ones

Comment: Yes, but what is SideBarContainter? Your own class inheriting from JPanel?

Comment: SideBarContainter is simply a Jpanel, (I use it to help with handleing mouse events like popup menu)

Comment: Default layout manager, should I switch to flowlayout maybe ?

Comment: What is the Dimension (d2) you pass to the SideBarContainer constructor used for? JPanel doesn't have a constructor accepting a Dimension. Additionally, FlowLayout is default for JPanel, but I'm not sure it correctly works with JScrollPane (due to preferred size calculation).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if you don't have to do it yourself, could be to use some SwingX component (like TaskPane etc.). Unfortunately, they seem to be in a transition over to java.net and thus many resources are not available as of now. However, there's a basic [download page](http://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/1.6.2/).